# Lower and upper bound on a real eigenvalue whose eigenvector components are non-negative

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given λ a real eigenvalue of a real n-by-by matrix **A** whose eigenvector has only non-negative components, I must show that λ is bounded by the minimum and maximum sums of the columns of **A**, that is

$$\min_{1 \le k \le n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ik} \le \lambda \le \max_{1 \le k \le n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_{ik}$$

I don't know how to approach this problem.

It looks closely related to the [Perron-Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) theorem, which asserts that for a positive matrix **B**, there is a eigenvector **v** with only positive components and an eigenvalue that satisfies the above inequation. Any ideas?

Comment: May $A$ have the negative elements? I am not sure I understood. We have Perron-Frobenius theroem that states this result for positive matrix and some eigenvalue/vector. You try to prove the more general result for general matrices. Why it should be true?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Yes in theory (but it could still be that no such matrix A with negative elements exists)

Comment: Again I am confused. What you are going to prove? The inequality or existence of $A$ such that this inequality holds?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner The Perron-Frobenius theorem states that if a matrix has positive values, then there is an eigenvector with positive values and the above inequality holds. What I want to prove is that if a matrix has real values AND an eigenvector with non-negative values (with an associated real eigenvalue), then the inequality holds.

Comment: Yes but even The Perron-Frobenius theorem  does not claim that for any eigenvector with nonnegative values this inequality holds. Why then it should be true in your case?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner That's my original question. I didn't say that I had to use the Perron-Frobenius theorem, I just noted that it was similar to it.

Comment: "I must show" means that you know this is true or you want it to be true?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner I know it to be true. It's a "Prove that..." question.